# "There is no point in" or "There is not a point in"

Tags: differences, negation, no-not

I was thinking about these negations. Do these mean the same thing?

> There is no point in ...
>   There is not a point in ...

or:

> I have no clue
>   I do not have any clue

etc.

Comment: Generally the meanings are the same.  But in some cases one version is widely used while the other is not.  This would be awkward: **There is not a point in arguing with the boss.**  But this would be OK:  **There is not a point on any of these daggers.**

Answer (score 6):

The difference is in how idiomatic or natural the expressions are, and not in the literal meanings. (I am a native American English speaker; others' intuitions may differ).

> **There is no point in...**  (idiomatic and natural)
>   **There isn't any point in...** (another natural alternative)
>   ***There is not a point in...*** (marked and unnatural, perhaps emphatic)
>
> **I have no clue.**  (idiomatic and natural)
>   **I haven't got a clue./I don't have a clue.** (also natural alternatives)
>   ***I do not have any clue.***  (marked and unnatural, perhaps emphatic)

So we could almost always use the first expressions of each pair that you provided  under normal circumstances. But we just as well could use the alternatives I listed instead. Finally, the last listed expressions don't sound right; they might only be used when we want to emphasize.

The meanings are the same, so it's a matter of what will sound natural.

Comment: But **any** requires a plural: So it should be:  _I do not have any clues_  or _I do not have a clue_.

Comment: @Jim not necessarily; clue has both a count-noun sense ('item of evidence') and a non-count-noun sense ('cognizance')

Comment: I'm not convinced *There is not a point in [sth]* would **ever** be used, either to convey that something serves no purpose, or that it contains no specific items of substance. I'm not particularly convinced about *I do not have any clue* either - it just sounds like something a non-native speaker might say.

Comment: I don't disagree they are not idiomatic - as I said. But a simple google search reveals millions of hits for both. This is evidence that it's not nonsense. The questioner asked if they mean the same; they do. It's just that one is more idiomatic.

Comment: However, given the objections, which are fair, I have attempted to clarify my answer.

Comment: I’m not disagreeing with your answer, but I should add that for me, as a native speaker of British English, “I haven’t got a clue.” is more idiomatic / natural than “I have no clue.”

Comment: "I don't have a clue" is another natural formation, but I'd use "I have no clue" just as readily.

Comment: @Jim: 'I don't have any idea.'

Comment: @BarrieEngland, Yes, I rarely use 'clue' except when I'm being particularly condescending and say things like, "Here's a dollar, buy a clue"  But ordinarily I would say, "I've got no idea" while many of my friends use "I have no clue."