# "There is no problem" or "there isn't any problem"

Tags: differences, negation, there-is, no-not

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“There is no point in” or “There is not a point in”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60042/there-is-no-point-in-or-there-is-not-a-point-in)

What's the difference between *there is no problem* and *there isn't any problem*? Are they both acceptable?

Comment: Yes, they are both okay grammatically, with slight different usages. How many different variations of the same statement do you have in your own native language? I am sure the answer is many. English is no exception.

Answer (score -1):

Semantically they are the same, but stylistically there may be occasions where one is preferable to the other. For example, I would prefer to write:

- There are no apple trees in the orchard.

rather than:

- There aren't any apple trees in the orchard.

My preference would be even stronger if I had the need to speak the sentence.